# Business logic in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Led by the recently read premise "Lean controllers and fat models" I've come to the conclusion that my controller might be *too fat* at the moment.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is simple Edit (POST) function where I'm trying to update *heavily* nested entities. What can be found here is a ViewModel (VM in the code) containing the following child ViewModels:

- ProductCategoriesVM (main ViewModel)
- ProductCategoryVM (multiple of those can assigned to the ProductCategoriesVM)
- ProductCategoryAttributesVM (multiple of those can be assigned to the ProductCategoriesVM)
- ProductCategoryAttributeVM (multiple of those can be assigned to the ProductCategoryAttributesVM)

ViewModelToModel is a function that, as the name suggests, converts ViewModel to the corresponding Model and is located within the controller. Should I do this differently?

What I think can be done differently (**better**) is a part where I, based on the input in the ViewModel, keep or remove the entities from the database. As you can see I'm repeating myself in ProductCategories part.

ProductCategories

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProductCategoriesVM productCategoriesVM)
    {
        bool exists;

        ProductCategoryDetail productCategoryDetail = ViewModelToModel(productCategoriesVM);
        uow.ProductCategoryDetailRepository.Update(productCategoryDetail);

        //Updating ProductCategory
        foreach (var productCategoryVM in productCategoriesVM.ProductCategories.ToList())
        {
            ProductCategory productCategory = ViewModelToModel(productCategoryVM);
            exists = uow.ProductCategoryRepository.Exists(productCategoryVM.idProductCategory);

            if (exists)
            {
                uow.ProductCategoryRepository.Update(productCategory);
            }
            else
            {
                uow.ProductCategoryRepository.Create(productCategory);
            }
        }

        //Updating ProductCategoryAttributes
        foreach (var productCategoryAttributesVM in productCategoriesVM.ProductCategoryAttributes.ToList())
        {
            ProductCategoryAttributeDetail productCategoryAttributeDetail = ViewModelToModel(productCategoryAttributesVM);
            exists = uow.ProductCategoryAttributeDetailRepository.Exists(productCategoryAttributesVM.idProductCategoryAttributeDetail);

            if (productCategoryAttributesVM.Keep)
            {
                if (exists)
                {
                    uow.ProductCategoryAttributeDetailRepository.Update(productCategoryAttributeDetail);
                }
                else
                {
                    uow.ProductCategoryAttributeDetailRepository.Create(productCategoryAttributeDetail);
                }

                foreach (var productCategoryAttributeVM in productCategoryAttributesVM.ProductCategoryAttributes.ToList())
                {
                    ProductCategoryAttribute productCategoryAttribute = ViewModelToModel(productCategoryAttributeVM);
                    exists = uow.ProductCategoryAttributeRepository.Exists(productCategoryAttributeVM.idProductCategoryAttribute);

                    if (exists)
                    {
                        uow.ProductCategoryAttributeRepository.Update(productCategoryAttribute);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uow.ProductCategoryAttributeRepository.Create(productCategoryAttribute);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (exists)
                {
                    uow.ProductCategoryAttributeDetailRepository.Delete(productCategoryAttributeDetail);

                    foreach (var productCategoryAttributeVM in productCategoryAttributesVM.ProductCategoryAttributes.ToList())
                    {
                        ProductCategoryAttribute productCategoryAttribute = ViewModelToModel(productCategoryAttributeVM);
                        uow.ProductCategoryAttributeRepository.Delete(productCategoryAttribute);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        uow.Save();

        return View(productCategoriesVM);
    }
```

I hope someone more experienced could help me shed the light on this one. Any other code reviewing suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: You have a lot of domain logic in your controller. If you're using a repository, either put the domain logic in the repository or add a service layer that accepts a DTO and communicates necessary changes to the repository layer. You should probably wrap this in a transaction to ensure atomic behavior as much as possible.

Remember that your view model should cleanly map to your view and should not specifically be tied to internal representations of entities/data and business logic. You should be able to restructure your view and view model without affecting anything else.

Comment: @AnthonyFawcett Thanks for a summary! Could you, maybe, add it as an answer with some simple examples if that wouldn't be a problem for you so I can get the grips with techniques more experienced StackExchangers use.

Comment: I will if I can find time to.

Comment: Personal preference here, but why not split this into multiple methods that each handle one specific thing (Four methods I believe).  I.E. A only cares that is has B1 and B3 as children, it doesn't care about B1 through B4's  C properties.  B1 only cares that it has C2, C3 and C5, and doesn't care about C's D properties.